# restlet content type, versioning with restlet

Tags: java, apache-camel, restlet

I am exposing a rest service by using restlet with camel.

I have exposed a rest service as one end, and at another end I have overridden process method.
The code looks like below,

```
from("restlet:/service/serviceName/{serviceId}?restletMethod=PUT").process(new Processor() {
  @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
    //Implementation goes here.
  }
}
```

I have two issues here.

- I am not able to set the content type for the request
- I am not able
  to achieve versioning of content type

I tried with the following options.

```
setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, simple("application/json"))

setHeader(Exchange.ACCEPT_CONTENT_TYPE, simple("application/json"))
```

Still the issue is not solved. Is there any other option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your route is a from. This means you send a request to it.

1. Send a request to it from fiddler, chrome or somewhere else with the headers you want.
2. Add logging to the route that prints out the entire exchange including the headers. Here you will find Content-Type, and all the other HTTP headers as well.
3. To access them you need to access the header on the Exchange like any other header.

I don't understand why you are setting headers there.

For example in your process code you can do like this:

```
String contentType=(String) exchange.getIn().getHeader("Content-Type");
        if (contentType.equals("application/json")) {
//do something
}
```

Note, you need to verify that the header is called Content-Type and not content-type or something similar since RESTLET is case sensitive. That is why you need to add the logging to see the name of the header on the exchange.

Comment: Nice one, yeah its working for me. But, in this case the request is coming inside the process method, then we are verifying the Content-Type.
I am looking to do the same verification on the initial stage it self, like if we are using jersey/cxf and we are trying to send a request with wrong Content-Type, the service it self won't allow to process the request. **Does the same kind of verification is possible here ??**

Comment: Refer to the camel-restlet documentation. http://camel.apache.org/restlet.html , you can set the parameter CamelAcceptContentType in the restlet URI so you restrict to a Content-Type of your choice.